# Earliest piano lyre?

Tags: piano, history, harpsichord

When was the first piano built/marketed/sold whose pedals were mounted on what we now call a lyre, instead of onto a harpsichord-like crossbar between the front legs?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it depends on whom you ask. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_pedals#Knee_levers) is a very interesting read on the subject of piano pedals and their history. Here's a quote of the material most relevant to your question:

> Americus Backers' 1772 grand, his only surviving instrument, has what are believed to be original pedals, and is most likely the first piano to use pedals rather than knee levers. A square piano built by Adam Beyer of London in 1777 has a damper pedal, as do pianos built by John Broadwood, ca. 1783.

So, somewhere in the late 18th century.

Comment: Wikipedia quotes a coffee table book, regarded as unauthoritative two decades after publication.  The article about [Backers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americus_Backers) contradicts a lyre:  "Americus's other innovation was to mount his instrument on a dedicated three-legged trestle stand. The two front legs of this stand incorporated linkages to the instrument from two pedals...."

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Well, I guess you know more about it than me already. :) Have those authorities who regard it as unauthoritative written any more authoritative books of their own?